# Does ranging the SQL query speed up the query time?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

There is a table `words` contains `word` and `id` columns and 50000 records. I know words with the structure `%XC%A` are between the `id=30000` and the `id=35000`.

Now consider the following queries:

`SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%XCX%A'`

and

`SELECT * FROM words WHERE id>30000 and id < 35000 and word LIKE '%XCX%A'`

From time consuming perspective, is there any difference between them?

Comment: Well, neither query is valid, so I'm not sure how we can advise

Comment: @Strawberry not valid because of ' '?

Comment: Absent inverted commas

Comment: It works in phpmyadmin UI, but I am not talking about syntax, I am talking about structure of a query :|

Comment: Does column `id` have a index ? In my understanding, LIKE '%XCX%A' will not use index even there is a index  on column `word`. I should declare that even you got a index on column `id`, SELECT * FROM words WHERE id>30000 and id < 35000 may not use index, so it all depends.

Comment: @ChaojunZhong yes `id` has index

Comment: @ChaojunZhong it deponds on what else?

Comment: @Drupalist if there are many(many depends on hit records and total records,10% I remember but not sure) records lies between id>30000 and id < 35000, mysql may think these records may in different blocks, so even you use the index, you have to read many blocks and do the like filter, so mysql will not use index and scan all the blocks, like the accepted answer's situation.

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html  for more info. paragraph above **Hash Index Characteristics**

Comment: @ChaojunZhong there are about 500 records between 30000 and 35000

Comment: @Drupalist you can use explain to see if index is used , like the accepted answer.I say it all depends is to reminder you that though you got a index, mysql may not use it, so you should always use explain to check it when you are not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's find out...

Here's a data set of approximately 50000 words. Some of the words (but only in the range 30000 to 35000) follow the pattern described:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%XCX%A';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | words | index | NULL          | word | 14      | NULL | 50976 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM words WHERE id>30000 and id < 35000 and word LIKE '%XCX%A';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | words | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 1768 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

We can see that the first query scans the entire dataset (50976 rows), while the second query only scans rows between the given ids (in my example there are approximately 1768 rows between ids 30000 and 35000; there are lots of unused ids, but that's just a side effect of the way in which the data was created).

So, we can see that by adding the range, MySQL only has to scan (at worst) one fifth of the data set (5000 rows instead oof 50000 rows). This isn't going to make much of a difference on such a small dataset, but it will on dataset 100, or 1000 times this size.

One thing to note is that the two queries will return the same data set (because we know that valid values are only to be found within that id range), but they won't necessarily return the dataset in the same order. For consistency, you would need an ORDER BY clause.

Another thing to note is, of course, that there's no point indexing `word` (for this query anyway), because `'%...'` cannot use an index.

Comment: Actually there are about 20 words that follow the pattern. In this case I think it worth to use `id`, right?

Comment: No. It makes almost no difference

Comment: @Drupalist - The leading wildcard (`%`) is important.  Limiting the number of rows (via a range on `id`) is important.  Do the `id` range _when you can_`.